# $\left[0,1\right]\cap\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{2^n}\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\left[0,1\right]$?

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove that:

$$\left[0,1\right]\cap\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{2^n}\mathbb{Z}$$

is dense in $\left[0,1\right]$?

Someone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @João, welcome to MSE. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for $a_1,\ldots,a_N\in\{0,1\}$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^Na_k2^{-k} = \left(\sum_{k=1}^N2^{N-k}a_k\right)\cdot2^{-N}\,\in\,\frac 1{2^N}\mathbb Z.
$$
So, you can produce every number $(0.a_1\ldots a_N)_2$ with your set.

Comment: Oh, yes, off course! Since $N$ is arbitrary, I can write any $x\in\left[0,1\right]$.

Comment: @JoãoMaia: Not exactly, the set above is countable, $[0,1]$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $x \in [0,1]$ then there is some $x_n \in {1 \over 2^n} \mathbb{Z} \cap [0,1]$
such that $|x-x_n| < {1 \over 2^n}$.